# Django - type of request

Tags: django

I'm puzzled with this behaviour. The code simply prints the type of the request. The first method works, but the second returns an empty string. The type of the class is django.corehandlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest.

---

(edit to clarify)

```
def someview(request):                                                                                                                                        
    html+="<p>type of the request each char "                                                                                                                 
    for i in range(47):                                                                                                                                       
        html+= (str(type(request))[i])                                                                                                                        
    html+="</p>"                                                                                                                                              

    html+="<p>type of the request each char "                                                                                                                 
    for i in range(47):                                                                                                                                       
        html+= repr(str(type(request))[i])                                                                                                                    
    html+="</p>"                                                                                                                                              

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

The result is the following. The second string is empty.

```
type of the request each char '<''c''l''a''s''s'' '"'"'d''j''a''n''g''o''.''c''o''r''e''.''h''a''n''d''l''e''r''s''.''w''s''g''i''.''W''S''G''I''R''e''q''u''e''s''t'"'"'>'

type of the request:
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? type(request) should give you '<type HttpRequest>' or so. And if you take the len() of that: 18 characters. So how do you get 47? What are you passing to the function? What's your goal?

Comment: Did you want to have "?" sign replaced by `str(type(request))` evaluation result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is why is the second line not printing anything? The answer to that is that you need `repr()`, not `str()`.

However, you realize it will *always* be the same WSGIRequest, right? You are printing the representation of the *class* of the `request` object.

You probably want [`request.METHOD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method).

Comment: Thanks. Why does str() not work? I would have thought that str(type(X)) would always have to return something.